# EditorTemplate and DateTimeOffset not working in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I am using an EditorTemplate for a DateTimeOffset field that consists of...

```
@model DateTimeOffset?
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:u}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTimeOffset.UtcNow), new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

This works in 90% of my forms, I get values like `2012-07-31 11:30:09Z`. However, I have one form that will not apply any formatting. The HTML output of the working input field and the non-working input field are the same.

Working...

```
<input class="datepicker hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-required="&amp;#39;Launch Time&amp;#39; must not be empty." id="LaunchTime" name="LaunchTime" type="text" value="2012-07-31 11:30:09Z">
```

Non-working...

```
<input class="datepicker hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-required="&amp;#39;Launch Time&amp;#39; must not be empty." id="LaunchTime" name="LaunchTime" type="text" value="07/31/2012 11:30:09 +00:00">
```

The only thing that I have found that fixes the problem is to change the TextBox name field...

```
@Html.TextBox("asdf", String.Format("{0:u}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTimeOffset.UtcNow), new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

However, this then changes my input field to...

```
<input class="datepicker hasDatepicker" id="LaunchTime_asdf" name="LaunchTime.asdf" type="text" value="2012-07-31 11:30:09Z">
```

which will then break the form submission, and removes the validation rules.

The model...

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:u}" , ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTimeOffset LaunchTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is the type for `LaunchTime` the same in both models - that is in one of them nullable and the other not?

Comment: Why are you using `Html.TextBox("")` instead of `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)`?

Comment: The same model is being used in all the forms.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the only format that seems to work for the datetime value is yyyy-mm-dd.  /s do not work.